# How to automatically install UWP app for UI tests on build machine

Tags: c#, uwp

My build machine needs to:

- clone repo
- build solution
- deploy app
- run app

UWP app needs to be deployed in OS, I cannot just run DLL. How can I deploy the app, so it can be consumed by `WinAppDriver`?

As I understand app needs to be i.e. visible in start menu. I could generate bundle and install it using powershell, but I think this is not a right way as visual studio can do it without generating bundle.

Comment: _"visual studio can do it without generating `bundle`"_ - well Visual Studio deploys an _unpackaged_ `appx` when you click **Debug**.  You can see it via `get-appxpackage -all`

Comment: @MickyD maybe I've stated it incorrectly, but I think that generating bundle on build is unnecessary - especially following your previous comment I think I should be able to run with `/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=CI` to generate .appxbundle, and then just run Add-AppxPackage.

Comment: Thank-you for edit.  Re last comment, sounds good.  If it works don't forget you can answer your own question by posting below :)